# Pick data from NodeClustring object

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, nomachine-nx

I was working with cdlib and detecting my data communities. but I need clusters of communities. how can I pick data from this object?

```
from cdlib import algorithms
import networkx as nx

coms = algorithms.louvain( G )
print(coms.data)
```

this is result of print(coms)

**<cdlib.classes.node_clustering.NodeClustering object at 0x7fe46ec70ac0>**

Answer (score 0):

I found it. but not sure it's good to do. but worked.

We can save it using

```
from cdlib import readwrite

readwrite.write_community_csv(coms, "communities.csv", ",")
```

then read again communities.csv dataset and use clusters data